# how to add two vectors so the second one is oriented from the first one?

Tags: vector, geometry, vectorization

I basicaly want to add two vectors so the second one is oriented form the first one
A , B are our vectors A is (0,1) and B is (1,0) and R is the result
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF6C8.png)

but i want B to be relative to A so when the A is (1,0) and B is (1,0)
i want the result to be [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9duX.png) and not [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0JeB.png)

it means that their dot product will always be the same when i chage the vector A

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out myself. The Basic idea is rotating a vector by a vector.
You can normalize the vector A and mark it as C. By swaping the x and y and negating y you can create vector D which is perpendicular to C, D = (C.y,-C.x) . C And D are now coordinates of your new local space.
Now you have to convert the vector from your local space to global space which is easily made by multipliing B(the vector to be rotated).x * D + B.y * C. The vector B is now rotated.
To get the final result just add A and rotated B.